# Blenderで.meshファイルを読み込みそれをfbxファイルでテクスチャ付きでエクスポートして読み込んでもテクスチャが反映されない理由が知りたい

Tags: blender

[マルチポスト先](https://teratail.com/questions/fcttd0lmy55mqb)

提示画像ですが以下の操作をblender2.7で実行して生成したfbxファイルをblender3.1で読み込むとテクスチャ付きで生成したはずのfbxファイルにテクスチャが付与されていません。これはなぜでしょうか？

モデル入手先: https://www.deviantart.com/sticklove/art/Tifa-Lockhart-840247039

###### バージョン

exportしたblender2.7
読み込んだBelnder3.1(最新版)

###### 行ったこと

Blenderのバージョンを下げてないと.mesh ファイルをインポートするアドオンが使えないのでBlender 2.7にて

１，選択　file->External Data-> Pack All .blend　をクリック
２，file->export->fbx
Path ModeにCopyを選択して右のチェックボックスにチェック

参考サイト：http://tatsuya1970.com/?p=1555
参考サイト：https://www.crossroad-tech.com/entry/export-import-fbx-blender-unity
参考サイト：https://vtuberkaibougaku.site/2022/01/26/blender-fbx/
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]